# How to define variables for PayPal purchase

Tags: php, web, paypal

So im looking through some examples for PDT for **Paypal purchases**.

Ive come across this https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_pdt.php so far so good. In the example some variables are accessed, hence

```php
    $firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
    $lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
    $itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
    $amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];
```

(PHP, Line 42)

**What im trying to do** is after a purchase is completed to insert a row into a table, Though since after the payment the user is redirected, the redirect site `accepted.php` wouldn't know which table to use. So i thought these variables may be the solution.

I was wondering where i can define these variables, or in a sense how they are assigned? Essentially **some general info** about where these variables came from and how they function.

Comment: Question is, are you getting anything back? If you read the code, this is a parsed response from the PHP Curl function. Line 23 defines $res which is then parsed by exploding the response into an array in lines 30 and a blank array in 31. Then the output of $res array is parsed into the keyarray from 32 thru 54. If you're not getting a response back or the response is not what is expected, might be best to find out why. The last update to that file is 2017. There might be changes in the response API since. Might have to use this as a base and tweak for your needs with the latest API changes.